# "scl load gcc-toolset-11" run failed

Tags: linux, bash, gcc

I want to install gcc-11 in Rocky Linux 8.6.
At first, I install `gcc-toolset-11`,

```bash
$ sudo dnf install gcc-toolset-11
```

Then I want to load it to the current bash.

```bash
$ scl load gcc-toolset-11
ERROR: Unable to locate a modulefile for 'gcc-toolset-11'
```

But it failed. I want to know how to let `scl load` work normally.

Comment: A work-around may be to "source /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-11/enable" as that appears to be the core functionality of "scl load", but I can't test further at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

According to the man page for gcc-toolset-11, it only supports the `enable` command. It also states that you can run `scl gcc-toolset-11 enable bash` to execute the bash command with the gcc-toolset-11 environment, which should be equivalent to what the `load` command would do.

Example:

```
[root@localhost ~]# scl enable gcc-toolset-11 bash
[root@localhost ~]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9.1.0.3)
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@localhost ~]# exit
exit
[root@localhost ~]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18.0.2)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `enable` instead of `load` .
See reference: [CentOS Software Collections (SCL)](https://wynton.ucsf.edu/hpc/software/scl.html)